# Add link in admin form - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, forms, download-link

I am creating a module for check distance from store to various area. For this, I need to give sample csv file format to store managers so they can format their csv files and upload in admin-side.

I need to put that link besides file-browse button.

For that, I have created below code.

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'csv_file',
        'file',
        [
            'name'  => 'csv_file',
            'label' => __('Upload Csv File'),
            'title' => __('Upload Csv File'),
            'note' => '<br><span id="sample-file-span" 
                                    . '<a id="sample-file-link" href="#">'
                                    . __('Download Sample File')
                                    . '</a></span>',
        ]
    );
```

By this, I can see the link.

My questions are,

**Where I put my sample csv file in my module ?**

**What to write code in *href* attribute so store-manager can download it ?**

Advanced Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create custom type in form

```
$fieldset->addType('csvfile', '\Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Youblock\Renderer\Csvfile');

$fieldset->addField(
    'file',
    'csvfile',
    [
        'name'  => 'csvfile',
        'label' => __('csvfile'),
        'title' => __('csvfile'),

    ]
);
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Yourblock/Renderer/Csvfile.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Yourblock\Renderer;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class Csvfile extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
{
    protected $_assetRepo;

    public function __construct( 
         \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo
    ) {
         $this->_assetRepo = $assetRepo;
    }

    public function getElementHtml()
    {
         $csvFile = $this->_assetRepo->getUrl('Vendor_Module::csv/yourfile.csv');
         $csvLink = "<a href=".$csvFile." target='_blank'>Download Sample File</a>";
        return $csvLink;
    }

}
```

**Copy yourfile.csv at**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/csv/yourfile.csv

Comment: Thank you so much @Prince Patel ! Its working exactly what I want :)

Comment: @Prince how can I get the value of file element in renderer?

Comment: @Rajan Soni $this->getValue();  used these get value of element.